# Hibernate list mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I am trying to map entities so I'll have following or similar effect (preferably without OrderItem.quantity) :

[image]

Here is my entity :

```
public class Orders implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
private UserCreds user;
@OneToMany
private List<Item> orderedItems;
```

I end up with OrdersItem join table mapped with just 2 columns :
 **item_id** and **order_id**, both are keys
thus it wont let me persist order with repeating items. Adding id column for OrderItems should do the trick:

```
OrdersItem table that I except:
| ID | ORDER_ID | ITEM_ID
  1    25         31
  2    25         31
  3    25         12
  4    25         12
  5    25         62
```

etc..
But I just couldnt get that working, or maybe my solution is completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an element collection here might be a better option. An element collection works well for providing relationships with attributes.

It could look like this in your `Orders` class:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Item, Integer> itemQuantities = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
```

**EDIT**: You can use `@ElementCollection` when the **value** type of the `Map` is a basic type or an `Embeddable`. `Integer` is a basic type.

If you decide to use an entity as the **value** type of the `Map`, you have to use `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`

The **key** type has no influence on the annotation selection in this case, so you could use an `Item` or a `Long` as key, without having to change the annotation. This does however have an impact on the physical mapping annotations you can use.

Comment: "The JPA 2.0 specification clearly states that @ ElementCollection is for basic types and embeddables" , and I think I need both classes as @ Entity. Following solution leads to 
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @ OneToMany or @ ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: Entity.Orders.itemQuantities[java.lang.Integer]
(targetClass) wont help